# Renaming an environment then replace the original environment

Tags: environments

In my case, I'm only interested in the `proof` environment, but I believe it applies to any other environment.

I would like to present the `proof` environment in two different formats, the "Default" format and the "Modified" one.

Since I used the "Modified" format more often, I would like the `proof` environment to yield the "Modified" format. However, I would like to preserve the "Default" format to be used from time to time, such as changing it to the environment `proof2`.

In other words:

```
\begin{proof}
    % "Modified" format
\end{proof}

\begin{proof2}
    % "Default" format
\end{proof2}
```

As a MWE, say I want the "Modified" format to replace the *Proof.* to *Modified.*, and the `\qedsymbol` to a `\blacksquare`. My attempt would be:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}

\newenvironment{proof2}[1][Proof]
  {\begin{proof}[#1]}
  {\end{proof}}
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][Modified]
  {\begin{proof2}[#1]\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}}
  {\end{proof2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
    ``Modified'' format.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof2}
    ``Default'' format.
\end{proof2}

\end{document}
```

which does not work (TeX capacity exceeded), likely due to cyclic definition.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you have a circular definition. Solution: alias the commands to save the original.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}

% alias the \proof and \endproof commands
\NewCommandCopy{\amsthmproof}{\proof}
\NewCommandCopy{\endamsthmproof}{\endproof}

\renewenvironment{proof}[1][Modified]
  {\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}\amsthmproof[#1]}
  {\endamsthmproof}
\newenvironment{proof2}
  {\amsthmproof}
  {\endamsthmproof}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
    ``Modified'' format.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof2}
    ``Default'' format.
\end{proof2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Even if it *seems* to work, don't use `"` for the closing quotes, but `''` (two apostrophes).

#### *Caveat*

If you have an older TeX installation with LaTeX prior to 2020-10-01, you can do

```
% alias the \proof and \endproof commands
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\amsthmproof}{\proof}
\LetLtxMacro{\endamsthmproof}{\endproof}
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried your code, and it returns an undefined control sequence error. I'm not sure but it appears to be `\NewCommandCopy` that is causing the problem.

Comment: @ClementYung You seem to have an outdated TeX system. But not all is lost, see the addition to my answer.

Comment: The addition works perfectly. Thank you!